# How to display a table using more than one API

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm react beginner. I'm using React/Redux to create an admin page. The problem is I use more than one API in one table. API is dependent(e.g : /api/employment, /api/employment/{employment_PK}/status).
I want to get the data for employment_PK from /api/employment and then call /api/employment/{employment_pk}/status to get the data.
I've looked up a variety of questions, but there are no questions that fit my situation.
How can I successfully call two APIs to fetch data and create a table?
I need your little help, Thanks!

I have tried this method.
I know something is wrong, but I don't know how.

types.js

```
export const GET_EMPLOYMENTS_PART = 'GET_EMPLOYMENTS_PART';
export const GET_EMPLOYMENTS_PART_SUCCESS = 'GET_EMPLOYMENTS_PART_SUCCESS';
export const GET_EMPLOYMENTS_PART_ERROR = 'GET_EMPLOYMENTS_PART_ERROR';
export const GET_EMPLOYMENT_ONE_SUCCESS = 'GET_EMPLOYMENT_ONE_SUCCESS';
export const GET_EMPLOYMENT_ONE_ERROR = 'GET_EMPLOYMENT_ONE_ERROR';
```

employment_actions.js

```
export const getEmploymentParts = (offset, limit) => async dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: GET_EMPLOYMENTS_PART });
    try {
        const data = await employmentAPI.getEmploymentPart(offset, limit);
        dispatch({ type: GET_EMPLOYMENTS_PART_SUCCESS, data });
    } catch(e) {
        dispatch({ type: GET_EMPLOYMENTS_PART_ERROR, error: e });
    }
}

export const getEmploymentsOne = (uuid) => async dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: GET_EMPLOYMENT_ONE });
    try {
        const data = await employmentAPI.getEmploymentOne(uuid);
        dispatch({ type: GET_EMPLOYMENT_ONE_SUCCESS, data });
    } catch(e) {
        dispatch({ type: GET_EMPLOYMENT_ONE_ERROR, error: e });
    }
}
```

employment_reducer.js

```
export default function employmentReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_EMPLOYMENT_ONE:
            return {
                ...state,
                employment: {
                    loading: 'loading...',
                    data: null,
                    error: null
                }
            }
        case GET_EMPLOYMENT_ONE_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                employment: {
                    loading: 'loading success...',
                    data: action.data,
                    error: null
                }
            }
        case GET_EMPLOYMENT_ONE_ERROR:
            return {
                ...state,
                employment: {
                    loading: 'loading error...',
                    data: null,
                    error: action.error
                }
            }
            case GET_EMPLOYMENTS_PART:
                return {
                    ...state,
                    employments: {
                        loading: 'loading...',
                        data: null,
                        error: null,
                    }
                };
            case GET_EMPLOYMENTS_PART_SUCCESS:
                return {
                    ...state,
                    employments: {
                        loading: 'loading success...',
                        data: action.data,
                        error: null,
                    }
                };
            case GET_EMPLOYMENTS_PART_ERROR:
                return {
                    ...state,
                    employments: {
                        loading: 'loading error...',
                        data: null,
                        error: action.error,
                    }
                };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

employment_table.js

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const {data} = useSelector(state => state.employments.employment);

useEffect(() => {
     dispatch(getEmploymentParts(pageSlice, pageLimit))
}, [pageSlice, pageLimit, dispatch]);

const userJob = (uuid) => {
    if(data){
       let employment_uuid = null;
       employment_uuid = data.filter(it => new RegExp(uuid).test(it.uuid));
    if(employment_status.length !== 0) {
       const uuid_result = employment_status[0].uuid;
                
       nextApi(uuid_result);
    }
}
useEffect(() => {
    nextApi();
}, []);


const nextApi = (uuid_result) => {
    dispatch(getEmploymentsOne(uuid_result))
}


return (
        <div className="table-wrapper">
            <Table hover size="sm">
                <thead>
                    <tr align="center">
                        <td>name</td> 
                        <td>phone</td>
                        <td>employment status</td>
                        <td>company name</td>
                        <td>payment date</td>
                        <td>hired</td>
                        <td>resigned</td> 
                    </tr> 
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {data.map((data) => {
                        return (
                            <tr align="center" key={data.uuid}>
                                <td>{data.name}</td> 
                                <td>{data.phone}</td>
                                <td>{UserJob(data.uuid)}</td>
                                <td>{data.company_name}</td>
                                <td>{data.payday}</td>
                                <td>2020-01-01</td>
                                <td>2020-01-01</td>
                            </tr>
                        )
                    })}
                </tbody>
            </Table>
        </div>
    )
```

Comment: Post your attempts.

Comment: I've posted what I tried!

Comment: Did you try async await ?

Comment: Where should I try? Tried both Action and API.

Answer (score 0):

tried async/await functions?

```
const getData = async () => {

   const results = await fetch('/api/employment');
   const resultsFinal = await fetch(`/api/employment, /api/employment/${results.employment_PK}/status`);
   
   console.log('resultsFinal', resultsFinal);

}
```

Comment: I haven't used fetch. This is a very new way. Is this what you use when calling the API? I am making API calls this way. I'll attach some code.

Comment: export const getEmploymentOne = async (uuid) => {
    const response = await axios.get(`${URL}/api/v4/employment/${uuid}/status`, {
        accept: 'application/json',
        headers: {
            authorization: `Token ${localStorage.getItem('Token')}`
        }
    });
    return response.data.results;
};

Comment: axios or fetch, same logic with async await.

Comment: I tried but didn't get the desired result. Or maybe it's something I don't understand your answer. Anyway, Thank you. I'll have to think this problem more.